# How can you instantly get armor, an iron sword, a bow and arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a minecraft server and I was wondering how to instantly get armor already put on the players, a sword, bow and arrows, without people getting the stuff themselves. How can I do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your problem is that `@p` is selecting other players?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_sword
/give @p minecraft:bow
/give @p minecraft:arrow 20
/give @p minecraft:iron_helmet
/give @p minecraft:iron_chestplate
/give @p minecraft:iron_leggings
/give @p minecraft:iron_boots
```

If you want to do different materials, switch the iron with and other material it can be made with.

Comment: your username will give it to you only                                                                 @p will target nearest player                                                                              @r will target a random player                                                                              @a will target all players                                                                                       @e will target all entitys

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/item` command to put items inside of player inventory slots and mobs. (You can replace `@p` with a username or `@e[type=minecraft:<mob>]` and `@e[name=<mob name>]` for an entity).

Here is a basic representation of a player with the use of an iron chestplate:

```
item replace entity @p armor.chest with minecraft:iron_chestplate 1
```

## Sources

[Commands/item - Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/item)
[Slot - Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slot)

Comment: How is this better than the /give command suggested in the other answer?

Comment: This is better because you can make armor (for example) already become equipped without the player having to do anything. The `/item` places an item in the specified slot given; the `/give` command just places it in the first empty inventory slot that it finds.